# Django / Python - Date joined check

Tags: python, django

I have the following code:

```
currentUser = request.user
date_joined = currentUser.date_joined

if date_joined < datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(seconds=20):
     DO SOME STUFF
```

However, I get the following error:

```
"can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes"
```

I do have "USE_TZ = True" in my settings.

Is there a quick dirty why of tweaking my if statement to check if the date someone joined is less than 20 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start_time = date_joined .datetime_start.replace(tzinfo=utc)
end_time = datetime.datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=utc)
```